# Azure devops release fails: file not found, even though it was used in an earlier step

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, release

I have a yaml pipeline to release a virtual machine. We release using the same template to the dev, test en acceptance environment (each environment is a different stage).
Dev and test are running fine. Acceptance fails.

Within the stage are a number of jobs, each job consisting of different steps. Within one job, the same powershell script (which is part of the repo, so not an inline script) is used several times. The first two times it runs fine. Then a long install step happens (1h30m) and then the script needs to run again. But then the pipeline says this:

> ##[error]The term 'C:\azp\agent_work\6\s\scripts\start_stop-virtualmachine.ps1' is not
> recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
> verify that the path is correct and try again.

I checked if the filepath is EXACTLY the same as the previous times it was used. It is.

Is there any way that files can be deleted from an agent?

In case it may be relevant:

1. It's a release to azure.
2. The agents are hosted on containers
3. We had this issue with different agents in the agent pool
4. We have expanded the time a job can run, since the standard is 60 minutes before it's canceled.

[image: Release flow, steps highlighted]

Comment: Sounds like the long installation step corrupted the source files or directory. Just try to add a `cmd` task after the long installation step and set dir to check if the PowerShell script existing there.